# How to use URL parameters to have multiple pages in one page

Tags: php, html, url, url-parameters

I have a home page and I want some other pages like the about us page and contact us page to be in this page to reduce the amount of files and to have a less messy URL. I want something like `www.example.com/index.php?page=about` to open up about us page and similarly `www.example.com/index.php?page=contact` to open up contact us page.

How can I use URL parameters like these to have multiple pages in one page?

Comment: IN my experience this is the wrong approach.  It is much better to have more files that are smaller.  Especially since you are using something like PHP.  You can include header and footer files in each one.  Another negative thing is that the back button in the browser will not do much.

Comment: Use `$_GET['page']` to determine what content to include. What have you tried?

Comment: @Phil so far I've just written the code of the pages and didn't know how to link them with url parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use $_GET like this

```php
$par = filter_var ($_GET ['page'] ?? '', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

The `?? ''` gives you a blank string if the parameter is missing.  And you need to `sanitize` any **GET** parameters against attacks.

Then it depends on what you want.

You can include a file

```php
if ($page=='about')
{require_once 'about.php';}
```

Or you can change the url

```php
if ($page=='about')
{header('Location: about.php');}
```

If you do the latter, then this has to be before any html is output or echoed.

Comment: and then use an if to insert the code of the page i want to show?

Comment: Did that work for you ?  If it did then you should upvote the answer and perhaps tick it :-)

Comment: I almost forgot sorry